# Escaping @ at symbol in Ruby Elastic Search gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have the following code in the custom ES 'where' wrapper method

```
filter: { term: params }
```

Then we have a sample ES document that contains:

```
"emails" => { "email" => "johndoe@email.com" }
```

It is returned when my search is:

```
query.where("emails.email" => "johndoe")
```

but I get no results when:

```
query.where("emails.email" => "johndoe@email.com")
```

It seems like I have to escape at symbol somehow when using ES gem?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your field is analyzed using the default standard analyzer and is thus tokenized at the `@` sign.

You can see what ES has indexed by running the command below:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty' -d 'johndoe@email.com'
```

And the result is

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "johndoe",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "email.com",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

As you can see, your email field has been tokenized as two different tokens and that's probably why searching for `johndoe` works, while searching for the full email address doesn't.

There are a few ways out from here, but one way that would work is to create your own analyzer based on a [`pattern_capture` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) and use it as `index_analyzer` for your `emails.email` field.

```
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "email" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : 1,
               "patterns" : [ "([^@]+)", "(\\p{L}+)", "(\\d+)", "@(.+)" ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "email" : {
               "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
               "filter" : [ "email", "lowercase", "unique" ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "emails": {
           "properties": {
               "email": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "analyzer": "email"      <-- use the analyzer here
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

At indexing time, that analyzer will produce all of the following tokens, which will allow you to search for any parts of your email address:

- `johndoe@email.com`
- `johndoe`
- `email.com`
- `email`
- `com`